# How to prevent Spring Boot daemon/server application from closing/shutting down immediately?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, server, daemon

My Spring Boot application is not a web server, but it's a server using custom protocol (using Camel in this case).

But Spring Boot immediately stops (gracefully) after started. How do I prevent this?

I'd like the app to stop if Ctrl+C or programmatically.

```
@CompileStatic
@Configuration
class CamelConfig {

    @Bean
    CamelContextFactoryBean camelContext() {
        final camelContextFactory = new CamelContextFactoryBean()
        camelContextFactory.id = 'camelContext'
        camelContextFactory
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you expose your end point, can you share some code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Apache Camel 2.17 there is a cleaner answer. To quote http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html:

> To keep the main thread blocked so that Camel stays up, either include the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, or add camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true to your application.properties or application.yml file.

You will want the following dependency too:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency>`

Clearly replace `<version>2.17.0</version>` or use the camel BOM to import dependency-management information for consistency.

Answer (score 38):

I found the solution, using `org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner` + `Thread.currentThread().join()`, e.g.:
(note: code below is in Groovy, not Java)

```
package id.ac.itb.lumen.social

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class LumenSocialApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LumenSocialApplication.class)

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run LumenSocialApplication, args
    }

    @Override
    void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info('Joining thread, you can press Ctrl+C to shutdown application')
        Thread.currentThread().join()
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your main method? That doens't compile.

Comment: @stealth Rabbi static void main(String[] args)

Comment: OK, but look at main(). It looks like you're missing some parens. It does not compile.

"    SpringApplication.run LumenSocialApplication, args"

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi I'll mention that my code is Groovy, not Java

Comment: This will break integration tests that are using the `SpringBootTest` annotation.

Comment: This only works if your application is healthy. If it crashes it will hang instead of exiting, which is a problem.

Answer (score 16):

An example implementation using a CountDownLatch:

```
@Bean
public CountDownLatch closeLatch() {
    return new CountDownLatch(1);
}

public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);  

    final CountDownLatch closeLatch = ctx.getBean(CountDownLatch.class);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            closeLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    closeLatch.await();
}
```

Now to stop your application, you can look up the process ID and issue a kill command from the console:

```
kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot leaves the task of running the application to the protocol around which the application is implemented. See, for example, this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactor-thumbnailer/):

> Also required are some housekeeping objects like a `CountDownLatch` to keep the main thread alive...

So the way of running a Camel service, for example, would to be to run Camel as a [standalone application](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html) from your main Spring Boot application class.

Comment: the 'this guide' link is broken.

Comment: It appears Spring revamped their quides and the original article is not available any more.

Answer (score 4):

All threads are completed, the program will close automatically.
So, register an empty task with `@Scheduled` will create a loop thread to prevent shutdown.

file application.yml

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

file DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

file KeepAlive.java

```
@Component
public class KeepAlive {

   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
   private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1 * 1000 * 60) // 1 minute
   public void reportCurrentTime() {
       log.info("Keepalive at time {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
   }
}
```

Comment: This can be an answer and not a comment. Please read the rules.

Answer (score 4):

This is now made even simpler.

Just add `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` to your application.properties

Answer (score 0):

My project is NON WEB Spirng Boot.
My elegant solution is create a daemon thread by CommandLineRunner.
Then, Application do not shutdown immediately.

```
 @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner deQueue() {
        return args -> {
            Thread daemonThread;
            consumer.connect(3);
            daemonThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    consumer.work();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.info("daemon thread is interrupted", e);
                }
            });
            daemonThread.setDaemon(true);
            daemonThread.start();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

To keep the java process alive when not deploying a web application set the webEnvironment property to false like so:

```
 SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication();
 sa.setWebEnvironment(false); //important
 ApplicationContext ctx = sa.run(ApplicationMain.class, args);
```

Answer (score -5):

for springboot app to run continously it has to be run in a container, otherwise it is just like any java app all threads are done it finishes,
you can add

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and it will turn it into webapp, if not you are responsible keeping it alive in your implementation

Comment: Like I said above, it's not a web server. So my question is... how do I simulate Tomcat's behavior? Do I stall the main thread or something like that? What's the "official" way to do this?