# In a Spring-Boot application without web server, what is the correct way to keep it running?

Tags: java, spring-boot, daemon

I have written a small spring-boot application without embedded servers. It is intended to run from command line and stay running until the VM gets signalled. What is the intended way of in the spring-boot framework (v2.0) to keep the application alive as a service? Should I have a `Thread.currentThread().wait();` as last statement in my `run(ApplicationArguments args)` method?  Is there an enabling  annotation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Spring Boot daemon/server application from closing/shutting down immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017784/how-to-prevent-spring-boot-daemon-server-application-from-closing-shutting-down)

Comment: it indeed looks duplicate, but not conclusive, and likely outdated. Most hints look very hacky.

Comment: `System.in.read` would block until the first key stroke... I want the thing just wait for Crtl-C.

Comment: @Kai the solultion given in this answer seems the right approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020806/1976843 better than waiting for a key stroke

Comment: @JEY That approach is bad as it will also work on all SpringBootTest tests. Hence those tests won't stop.

Comment: The solution with adding an empty scheduled task seems the least hacky one. @Scheduled(fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE)
public void doNotShutdown() {} It even works with the most basic Spring Boot Starter.

Comment: @SvenDöring you are right about that but if you are doing Unit Test without SpringBootTest this work. Enabling Scheduling is an idea. I didn't check but maybe since 2018 they are new solutions.

Answer (score -1):

from `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer`, Official.

```java
    private void startDaemonAwaitThread(DisposableServer disposableServer) {
        Thread awaitThread = new Thread("server") {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                disposableServer.onDispose().block();
            }

        };
        awaitThread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        awaitThread.setDaemon(false);
        awaitThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: that kind of contradicts the question condition of having a Spring-Boot application without a webserver, doesn't it?

Comment: I just assume there is another server instead of default web server, so it is necessary to keep application running. Refer to the official implementation, you can start a thread which blocked and waiting your server close.